# sqlite3 results set in swift returning extra data

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to fetch a number of records from a sqlite3 database and load them into an array.  The code I have written, which seems to function correctly at least as far as retrieving the correct number of records with the right values from the db is

```
    while(results?.next() == true) {
        println("Got a result")

        var sname = results?.stringForColumn("surname")
        var fname = results?.stringForColumn("firstname")

        println("Retrieved \(sname) ,\(fname)")
    }
```

The problem I have is that when I try to access the variables in the println statement what it yields is

```
Retrieved Optional("Smiles") ,Optional("Dick")
```

I have seemingly tried everything to get just the values  but keep getting the Optional(" ") added.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that is a bug; I think it is a feature, and how Swift deals with the possibility of your being returned NULL for any of these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
println("Retrieved \(sname!) ,\(fname!)")
```